# Wordpress get_posts custom category

Tags: wordpress, loops, post, get

can you guys help me with this, I am trying to filter only the nightlife event on my post loop here the code,

```
var locations = [<?php 

$posts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'category' => 'nightlife'
));

if( $posts ): ?>

                <?php foreach( $posts as $post ):
setup_postdata( $post );
?> {
                    lat: <?php the_field('lattitude'); ?>,
                    lng: <?php the_field('longitude'); ?>,
                    info: '<div class="onMapSingleWrapper"><h1 class="onMapTitle"><?php the_title(); ?></h1><p class="onMapDate"><?php the_field('date_de_levenement'); ?></p><p class="onMapPrice"><?php the_field('prix_de_levenement'); ?>$</p><p class="onMapFilter"><?php the_field('filtres'); ?></p></div>'
                },

                <?php endforeach; ?>

                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

                <?php endif; ?>
            ];

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

I always got all my post, I just want the nightlife category post.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got it finally, here if someone need it

```
$catSelect = '';

$posts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'category_name' => $catSelect
));

if( $posts ): ?>

                <?php foreach( $posts as $post ):
setup_postdata( $post );
?> {
                    lat: <?php the_field('lattitude'); ?>,
                    lng: <?php the_field('longitude'); ?>,
                    info: '<div class="onMapSingleWrapper"><h1 class="onMapTitle"><?php the_title(); ?></h1><p class="onMapDate"><?php the_field('date_de_levenement'); ?></p><p class="onMapPrice"><?php the_field('prix_de_levenement'); ?>$</p><p class="onMapFilter"><?php the_field('filtres'); ?></p></div>'
                },

                <?php endforeach; ?>

                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

                <?php endif; ?>
            ];

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```